# Visualize JSON data containing XY coordinate location

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I have JSON data which includes X-Y grid location, quantity, and color.

```
[{"x":1,"y":2,"qty":5,"color":"red"},
 {"x":2,"y":4,"qty":10,"color":"green"},
 {"x":3,"y":1,"qty":15,"color":"green"},
 {"x":4,"y":3,"qty":20,"color":"red"}]
```

I would like to visualize the JSON like this:

[image]

Preference is to use something in the Google Visualization API, but I'm open to other solutions.  I'm familiar enough with Javascript but wanted something that was a bit more plug/play.

Any ideas on where to begin?

Thanks as always!

Comment: You can use grid, svg or canvas. Almost similar thing was made by Ire Aderinokun. https://bitsofco.de/github-contribution-graph-css-grid/

Comment: I will take a look into your suggestions.  This helped me get to the correct search topic.  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution is not very elegant, but the idea was just to show how you can use basic Javascript with no additional libraries and just a bare  bit of CSS to achieve this. I threw in a couple of additional values with a blue background to test out additional data. You can make it look better with additional CSS - and expand on the feature set here, but just wanted to throw something up that would reproduce the chart in your image.

```js
var data = [{"x":1,"y":2,"qty":5,"color":"red"},
{"x":2,"y":4,"qty":10,"color":"green"},
//{"x":1,"y":4,"qty":8,"color":"blue"},
{"x":3,"y":1,"qty":15,"color":"green"},
//{"x":3,"y":2,"qty":77,"color":"purple"},
//{"x":5,"y":3,"qty":66,"color":"purple"},
//{"x":2,"y":1,"qty":22,"color":"blue"},
{"x":4,"y":3,"qty":20,"color":"red"}];

var chart = document.getElementById('chart');

var rows = 0;
var cols = 0;

// loop through and figure out how many rows and columns we will have
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 if (data[i].x > rows) rows = data[i].x;
 if (data[i].y > cols) cols = data[i].y;
 if (rows > cols) cols = rows;
 if (cols > rows) rows = cols;
 yCt = rows;
}


drawChart(rows,cols);

function drawChart(rows,cols) {
  var e = 0;
  var f = 0;

  while (e < rows) {
  
    var square = '<div class="square"><div class="header">'+yCt+'</div></div>';
    yCt--;
    chart.innerHTML = chart.innerHTML + square;
    addColumn(e); 
    e++;
  }
     if ( e == rows ) {
     addHeader()
     addValues()
    }
}
 
function addHeader() {
  var sq = document.getElementsByClassName('squareCol');
  var ct = 0;  
   for (var i = 0; i < sq.length; i++) {
     var element = sq[i];
  
    if (element.getAttribute('data-y') == 1) {
     ct++;
     var heading = document.getElementById('heading');
     heading.innerHTML = heading.innerHTML  + '<div class="headerCol">'+ct+'</div>';
   }
  }
}

function addColumn(rowNumber) {
  var row = document.getElementsByClassName('square')[rowNumber]
  for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {

     var x = i +1;
     var y = rows - (rowNumber);

     var squareCol = '<div class="squareCol" data-x="'+x+'" data-y="'+y+'"></div>';
     row.innerHTML =  row.innerHTML + squareCol;
  }
}
 

 
function addValues() {
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   var xVal = data[i].x;
   var yVal = data[i].y;
   var qty = data[i].qty;
   var color = data[i].color;
   var squares = document.getElementsByClassName('squareCol')
 
   for (var j = 0; j < squares.length; j++) {
     var element = squares[j];
     if (element.getAttribute('data-x') == xVal && element.getAttribute('data-y') == yVal) {
       element.innerHTML = '<div class="qty"><div class="inner">'+qty+'</div></div>'
       element.className += ' '+ color;
     }
   
   } // end loop squares
 }
 }
```

```css
#heading {
  position:absolute;
  margin-bottom:150px;
  margin-left:100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  position:absolute;
  line-height:4;
  vertical-align:text-bottom;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left:-50px;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:1.2rem;  
  font-weight:bold;
}

.headerCol {
  display:inline-block;
  border-width: 0;
  line-height:3;
  text-align: center;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:1.2rem;  
  width: 50px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.square {
  height: 50px;
}

.qty {
   position: relative;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:3;
}
.inner {
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
}
.squareCol {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px black;
  display:inline-block;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:1.2rem;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#chart {
  width: 600px;
  margin-left:100px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.green {
  background-color: #92D050;
}

.red {
 background-color: #FF0000;
}

.purple {
 background-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<div id="chart"></div>
<div id="heading"></div>
```

Comment: I will take a look at your code example.  This is helpful for me because I didn't really know where to begin.  Thank you

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this, maybe you'll get some other answers which will give you even more ideas! A table would be another way, I might even use a javascript template (I use Dust.js) and pass the data to the template to make the grid. Honestly the Google Visualization API looked like it would take a while to figure out how to configure to get what you want, which is why I did this for you. Good luck!